# Write data to existing excel (.xls) using apache POI, the workbook created give error excel lost some data

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xls

I'm trying to work on writing data to the excel file using apache POI-3.15-beta1, but when the workbook is created, the workbook becomes corrupted with lost some content which is some of the formula not working and table style is lost. If the original excel file is open while opening the updated excel, all content is there and there is no error. Other excel I tested working properly. Any suggestions of why this the problem happened and any solution?

This error popup before opening the excel:
[Lost content error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L7D1.png)

This popup after opening the excel when yes is clicked:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yZ2z.png)

[Edit] Cell A1:E5: [Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAr69.png)
I just used this java code here

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("D:/Template.xls");
Workbook workbook = null;
workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
inputStream.close();

Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

Cell cell= sheet.getRow(1).getCell(3);

cell.setCellValue(30);

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:/Test.xls"));
workbook.write(out);
out.close();
```

Comment: Can you upload the `Template.xls` somewhere? Or at least show a screenshot of first sheet Range `A1:E5` of that workbook. And please tell what content is in `D2` before the code runs.

Comment: @AxelRichter thank you for replying. I have updated my question added the screenshot of the sheet from `A1:E5`, also what is the `D2` means? if it's the excel cell content, then its empty currently.

Comment: Can it be that range `B1:*` or `B2:*` is part of a query table which pulls data from external source? If so, then this is the reason for the problem. You cannot change cell values in query tables using Apache POI.

Comment: I check the template again, there is no cell values that pulls data from external source. I try to find the reason behind the error so i tried removed two cells using list data validation and when it's removed the workbook created don't have the error, but the cell should supposedly not to be removed.

Comment: Yes, it answered my question! Thank you. Now I am looking for any workaround of the problem and ask another question related to this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but just to say that my current problem is more or less because of two cells with data validation like this [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51848887/finding-the-cause-of-excel-file-corruption). The problem is the excel file cannot be changed as it won't be valid anymore to use.